# directry not found while unziping file in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

when i try to unzip file then i am getting this error 'end of central directry not found'

```
async uplaodFolder() {
      await fs.mkdir(`${path.join(basePath, 'extract')}`, {recursive:true}).catch((err) => {
        //decide what you want to do if this failed
        console.error(err);
    });
    const bufferChunks = await this.readBufferDir(`${path.join(basePath, '/ldpi')}`);
    var mergeBuffer = Buffer.concat(bufferChunks);
    writeDir.writeFile(mergeBuffer)
    compressing.zip.uncompress(path.join(basePath, 'test.zip'), path.join(basePath, '/extract'))
    .then('uncompressDone')
    .catch('handleError');
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate zip file using Buffer contents in node.js using JSZip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46402066/how-to-generate-zip-file-using-buffer-contents-in-node-js-using-jszip)

Comment: this is not useful for me